# USB gaming mouse disconnects randomly

Tags: windows-7, usb, mouse

I bought a Hama Urage Evo gaming mouse. The problem is that the mouse disconnects randomly. The DPI button led shuts down, but the mouse light remains on, on the left and right sides. The mouse works well for 2-3 days. If I unplug it and plug it in again, the mouse turns on again.

I tried every energy solution and option in the device manager.  With a Genius xscroll mouse there is no problem, but with the Hama Urage Evo and Aula Killing the Soul, the mouse has this problem. The mouse exhibits the same problem when connected to another PC.

Is this a mouse problem or something else?

System information: Windows 7 Ultimate x64. Asus H81M-A, Intel G3420, 2x4 GB DDR3 1333Mhz ram, Geforce gtx 750 ti, 1TB HDD, 1 CD/DVD Drive and 500 W power supply.

Comment: I had somehow simmilar problems with my mouse and it turned out that the usb cable was broken. Have you checked it?

Comment: How can i check it? I didn't see any problems.

Comment: Take a look and move the cable around and see if it disconnects when mooving.

Comment: I tried but nothing happend so i think the cable is ok.

Comment: Hmm, I can't answer your question, but maybe you still have some vendor guarantee (in Germany it is 6 Months by law). Then I would send it back and take a replacement part. Not worth the trouble of fixing it yourself. Have you tested it on another PC?

Comment: Same, but i use it since 2 days and no problem again.

Comment: http://www61.zippyshare.com/v/CJ1i6YEr/file.html i uploaded the video what happend again.

Comment: Have you observed the same behavior on a different PC? If so, it is probably a Hardware issue.

Comment: Yes, same problem on a different pc. I bought another mouse i will try. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem mouse exhibits the same symptom on another computer, and another mouse works properly.  The means the problem is with the mouse rather than something else.

The symptoms you describe sound like a problem with the interface between the mouse and the computer rather than the portion that translates motion into data.  It could be a bad connection, like a defect in the cable or a bad solder joint where the cable attaches inside the mouse, or a defect in the electronics in the mouse.

If you have some skill in diagnosing and repairing electronics, you could check for something simple and repairable.  Unless it was a very expensive mouse, you would have to judge how much time and effort that is worth vs. buying a new one.